# Why the "%.moc" does not work in my Makefile?

Tags: qt, makefile, moc

I have the following Makefile:

```
CC=g++ -std=c++17
MYCXXFLAGS=-Werror -Wall

clean:
    rm -f *.o main

a.moc: 
    @echo "mocing $@"

%.o: %.cpp %.moc
    @echo "all prerequisites $^"
    $(CC) $(MYCXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

Under the same directory where the Makefile lives, there is a file called "a.cpp".

When I do "make a.o", the following gets printed:

```
mocing a.moc
all prerequisites a.cpp a.moc
g++ -std=c++17 -Werror -Wall -o a.o -c a.cpp
```

Which is perfect. The "a.moc" gets identified and gets executed.

However, if I replace

```
a.moc: 
    @echo "mocing $@"
```

with

```
%.moc: 
   @echo "mocing $@"
```

Then the thing starts to change. Only the following stuff is printed:

```
g++    -c -o a.o a.cpp
```

It seems the introduction of "%.moc:" messes everything up. This is just a demo example. In my real environment, the "%.moc" really does some Qt mocing operation. I am wondering why "a.moc" can be identified as a valid target and gets executed, while "%.moc" cannot achieve the goal?

Comment: I don't see how your `makefile` can possibly output only `g++    -c -o a.o a.cpp` without also printing the `all prerequisites $^` text.  Please check that you are actually using the `makefile` you think you are.  Right now it appears that `make` is invoking an implicit rule rather than one you've written yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that make has a series of built-in implicit rules.  One of these rules tells make how to build a `.o` file from a `.c` file.  You have added a rule that tells make how to build a `.o` file from both a `.c` and `.moc` file.  How does make choose which one to use?

The order of testing implicit rules is always that your rules are checked first, which is why it works when you have `a.moc`.  So why does it fail if you change that to `%.moc`?

The [full algorithm](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rule-Search.html) is described precisely in the GNU make manual.  Basically when you switch the rule from `a.moc` to `%.moc`, now the target `a.moc` is not mentioned anywhere in your makefile and so make doesn't consider that it "ought to exist" (see the algorithm for this definition).

You can fix this in many different ways:

You can list `a.moc` as an explicit prerequisite by adding:

```
a.o: a.moc
```

You can add the `-r` option to the GNU make command line to disable all built-in implicit rules:

```
$ make -r
```

You can add [the `-r` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) *into your makefile* by setting the `MAKEFLAGS` variable:

```
MAKEFLAGS += -r
```

You can alternatively [disable all suffix rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html) by adding this to your makefile:

```
.SUFFIXES:
```

Comment: Thanks. That works, though I am still struggling to understand the tricky implicit rule. For "%.o: %.cpp %.moc", it seems the implicit rule cannot find the "%.moc" target. Just clearing the :SUFFIXES, which disables the implicit rule, is good enough for me.

Comment: It could find it: it clearly DOES find it since if you remove the built in rule it works.  The problem is not that it's not found, the problem is that it's not looked for at all.  It's not looked for because make prefers the built-in implicit rule, because it's simpler (it can be used immediately, without having to build other things first).  So if you delete the implicit rule then your rule will be used since there's nothing better.